# Laravel 5.1 manyToMany with two classes and third in common

Tags: many-to-many, laravel-5.1

Here is the example:

Two classes: `chairs` and `tables`. Both of those classes are connected with third class `colours` with `ManyToMany` relations.

Let's say I have element of `chairs` class with two colours: `red` and `blue`.

How do I get matching `tables`, the tables that also belong to `red` and `blue`?

EDIT:

Chair model:

```
class Chair extends Model
{
    public function colours()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Colour')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Table model:

```
class Table extends Model
{
    public function colours()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Colour')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Colors model:

```
class Colour extends Model
{
    public function chairs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Chair')->withTimestamps();
    }
    public function tables()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tables')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Chair migration's up function:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('chairs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('name');
    });
}
```

Chair-Colour pivot table:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('chair_colour', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('chair_id')->unsigned();
//            $table->foreign('chair_id')->references('id')->on('chairs')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('colour_id')->unsigned();
//            $table->foreign('colour_id')->references('id')->on('colours')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

Remaining migrations (tables, chair_table, colours) are the same.
Foreign key constrains are commented out because I had problems when refreshing migrations with them included.

This is just manyToMany relation but I hope it helps. I just made this up since my code is more complicated so if You see any typos feel free to correct them or notify me in comments.

Thank You!

Comment: add your table structures to give more detail

Comment: @davejal I'm not sure if you are notified when I edit code so here's notification that I edited my code.

Comment: There are some errors (ex. the chair migration talks about 'orders' table) but I suppose that is wrong copy&paste or similar. Please clarify more the question: is a migration problem (so you could proceed by step to verify if everything works fine) or a eloquent query one?

Comment: In the second case It could help you use `hasManyThroughs` instead of `hasMany`.

Comment: @SamueleColombo Yes `orders` was just c/p typo. Everything is working fine I just don't know any simple way to get tables related to chairs with relations given as above. I'm trying to do this without using `foreach` loop five times. I went through Eloquent's relations but didn't see I could use anything else except `BelongsToMany`. I'll check it once again.